# Retrieving multiple data from mySQL in android using JDBC

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to retrieving the data from my database and populate it to a listView. But my code doesn't work, I also tried adding `Log.e` but I got nothing in the logcat. Here is what I tried to do:

btw I used `AsyncTask` here

---

**onPreExecute():**

`super.onPreExecute();`

---

**doInBackground():**

```
 try {
        Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
        if (con == null) {
            z = "Please check your internet connection";
        } else {

            String query = "select name from medicines";

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            lv.setAdapter(null);

            while (rs.next()) {

                myArrayList.add(rs.getString("name"));
                Log.e("qwerty","working");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        isSuccess = false;
        z = "Exceptions" + ex;
    }
    return z;
```

---

**onPostExecute():**

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MedicineSearch.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

That would be all, nothing appears on my logcat, that means the code doesn't work I guess, How can I fix this, or could there be another way around?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning String 'z' from doInBackground() but you need to return your myArrayList.

```
try {
    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
    if (con == null) {
        z = "Please check your internet connection";
    } else {

        String query = "select name from medicines";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        lv.setAdapter(null);

        while (rs.next()) {

            myArrayList.add(rs.getString("name"));
            Log.e("qwerty","working");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    isSuccess = false;
    z = "Exceptions" + ex;
}
return myArrayList;
```

Then Place a debugger in onPostExecute() to see if myArrayList has some data or not. 
**OnPosetExecute()** looks like this :

```
if(myArrayList.size() > 0){
//your set adapter code
}
```

Comment: I can't return `myArrayList`, It says Incopatible types

Comment: okay, then try changing your onPostExecute() and place a debugger on myArrayList.size() to see if anything is added in it or not.
if myArrayList.size() comes 0 then you know doInBackground() is not working as you want.

Comment: I tried adding that debugger inside the while loop and no response either. Also moving it outside the loop doesn't work T.T

Comment: okay, few things can happen here : either else condition is not executed at all OR your 'rs ' is empty right ? I would recommend you to check your table and column name again. make sure they exist and some data is present in table.  
oh and BTW you can remove **lv.setAdapter(null);** from doInBackground() its is unnecessary.